# How do I dismiss the DatePicker popup in UI tests that are running on iOS 16 devices?

Tags: swiftui, datepicker, xcuitest

I have defined a [DatePicker](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/datepicker) to have the [compact](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/datepickerstyle/compact) style, as follows:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var selectedDate = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
        DatePicker("Date Selected", selection: $selectedDate, displayedComponents: [.date])
            .accessibilityIdentifier("DatePicker")
            .datePickerStyle(.compact)
    }
}
```

I have defined a UI test that:

1. Taps on the DatePicker to show the DatePicker popup; then
2. Taps on one of the dates in the DatePicker popup to select that date; and then
3. Taps on the DatePicker again to dismiss the DatePicker popup.

Here's the code:

```swift
func test_date_picker() {
    let application = XCUIApplication()

    // 0. Launch the app
    application.launch()
        
    // 1. Show the DatePicker popup
    application.datePickers["DatePicker"].tap()
        
    // 2. Change the selected date
    application.datePickers.collectionViews.buttons["Friday, November 25"].tap()
        
    // 3. Dismiss the DatePicker popup
    application.datePickers["DatePicker"].tap()
}
```

This test works on iOS 14 and iOS 15 devices. Sadly, the final `application.datePickers["DatePicker"].tap()` call is failing on iOS 16 devices because `application.datePickers["DatePicker"]` is not hittable. How do I dismiss the DatePicker popup on iOS 16 devices?

You can find a minimal application project that demonstrates the problem [here](https://github.com/adil-hussain-84/SwiftUI-experiments/tree/master/App5).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted this same question on the Apple Developer Forums ([here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/720778)) and got back a response that has worked for me.

The idea is to define a `forceTap()` extension function on the [XCUIElement](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement) class, as follows:

```swift
extension XCUIElement {
    func forceTap() {
        if (isHittable) {
            tap()
        } else {
            coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx:0.0, dy:0.0)).tap()
        }
    }
}
```

Explanation: If the [XCUIElement](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement) instance is hittable, then the [XCUIElement](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement) instance's [tap()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement/1618666-tap) function is called. Otherwise, an [XCUICoordinate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuicoordinate) instance is created for a point within the [XCUIElement](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement) instance and that [XCUICoordinate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuicoordinate) instance's [tap()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuicoordinate/1615004-tap) function is called instead.

The final line of my test function is now changed to the following:

```swift
application.datePickers["DatePicker"].forceTap()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can dismiss a popup by tapping the `"PopoverDismissRegion"` button, as follows:

```
app.buttons["PopoverDismissRegion"].tap()
```

Note: I'm running my test on an iOS 17 device.

Comment: I just tried it on an iOS 17.2 simulator and I can confirm that it works. I can remember trying this on older versions of iOS and not having any luck with it. I'm glad to see that it's working for newer iOS versions.

Comment: I added a UI test in [this class](https://github.com/adil-hussain-84/SwiftUI-experiments/blob/master/App5/App5UITests/App5UITests.swift) which demonstrates the dismissing of a DatePicker popup with this technique. See the `test_date_picker_2()` function in that class.